# Is the following way to prove $\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = \det(A)^{n-2}\cdot A$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}$Is the following proof for $\adj(\adj(A)) = \det(A)^{n-2} A$ correct? ($A$ is invertible and squared):
$$\adj(\adj(A)) = \det(A)^{n-2} A$$
$$\adj(\det(A) A^{-1}) = \det(A)^{n-2} A$$
$$\det(\det(A) A^{-1}) (\det(A) A^{-1})^{-1} = \det(A)^{n-2} A$$
$$\det(A)^{n} \det(A)^{-1}\det(A)^{-1} A = \det(A)^{n-2} A$$
$$\det(A)^{n-2} A = \det(A)^{n-2} A$$
This is how I proved it and I want to know if I'm mistaken or not

Comment: You can write $3\times5$ or $3\cdot5$.   Writing $3*5$ is a workaround for occasions when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard.